# Freeradius filter ldap by group

Tags: ldap, openldap, radius, freeradius

I would like freeradius to check for group membership and allow access based on group membership:

My current config:

```
ldap {
        identity = 'cn=radius,ou=bindings,dc=company,dc=com'
        password = 'secret'
        server = 'ldap://openldap'
        base_dn = 'dc=company,dc=com'
        user {
                base_dn = "ou=users,${..base_dn}"
                filter = "(uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})"
        }
        group {
                base_dn = "ou=network-admins,ou=groups,${..base_dn}"
                filter = "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
                name_attribute = "cn"
                membership_filter = "(member=%{control:Ldap-UserDn})"
                cacheable_name = yes
        }
        update {
                control:NT-Password := sambaNTPassword
        }
}
```

I would want to achieve that only members of `network-admins` OU should get `Access-Accept` answer. Others should be rejected.

`network-admins` OU contains two groups (groupOfNames), this is where members are stored. Based on the actual group I would like to also set some attributes which should be sent to the radius client.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried putting these attributes here, in `ldap` mod file, however it did not work this way.

If I modified `default` server config, `post-auth` part, attribute is visible in response:

```
...
update reply {
      Mikrotik-Group := "%{control:LDAP-Group}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular `if{}` as part of your "authorize" block (docs say "post-auth", but that seems too late). The module will automatically turn the `==` comparison into an "any value equals" check, so you don't need a 'foreach'.

```
if (!(LDAP-Group == "network-admins")) {
    reject
}
```

The [rlm_ldap documentation](https://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/rlm_ldap#group-support) has more detailed examples in the "Group Support" section.